# MYSQL index a table for statistics

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a mysql table that stores info parsed from some 'logfiles'. The table has the following columns

```
 Table "logfiles"
 log_id        INT (PRIMARY)
 logfile_name  TEXT
 date          DATE (INDEX)
 username      TEXT (INDEX)
 field1        FLOAT
 field2        FLOAT
 field3        FLOAT
```

I would like to do a statistical query to sum things by year like this:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(date) AS year, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS active_days,
    COUNT(log_id) AS total_logs,
    COUNT(DISTINCT username) AS active_users,
    SUM(field1) AS total_field1,
    SUM(field2) AS total_field2
FROM 
    logfiles
GROUP BY 
    year
ORDER BY
    year ASC
```

What is the best way to index this table to get the query run fast (and use the index).

Currently the query takes 3 sec on 100000 rows. From EXPLAIN query i would understant that it is not using indexes.

```
id              1   
select_type     SIMPLE  
table           logfile_list    
type            ALL     
possible_keys   NULL    
key             NULL    
key_len         NULL    
ref             NULL    
rows            88963   
Extra           Using filesort
```

Thanks for any help 
Best regards
Pikot

Comment: I don't think an index would really do much here, because you are doing many table level aggregations, and there isn't a way to speed that up much.  For example, the distinct counts require MySQL to touch every record.

Comment: Plus mysql does not have functional indexes, so year(date) cannot be indexed in itself. You would have to use a stored generated column and index that.

Comment: @Shadow - In this situation (where the entire table is needed), it is of no use have a stored, indexed, generated column.

Comment: So, long story short - you have to let MySQL eat up more resources. Increase your `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. That's the usual answer these days.. you need all the data, therefore you want your CPU to get it fast. CPU can eat up a billion rows like it's nothing. The problem is getting that data to CPU. By increasing the variable I mentioned, you "allow" MySQL to store more data in memory. Memory = faster than HDD, therefore CPU gets data quicker and your query runs faster.

Answer (score 0):

- This, especially because of the `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` requires reading every row.
- Hence there will be a temp table created.
- Due to the existence of `TEXT`, it will necessarily be on-disk (MyISAM), not in memory (MEMORY).

Therefore, changing `username TEXT` to `username VARCHAR(55)` (or some reasonable size) *may* speed up the query, maybe by a factor of two.

Without the `COUNT(DISTINCT...)`, you could get a speedup of 10x by using [*summary tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

It is complex, but it is possible to get reasonably precise summarization of `COUNT(DISTINCT...)`.  See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uniques)